# import named volume from another docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose

After running `docker-compose file 1`, I want to use one of its named volumes in `docker-compose file 2`. I tried the below.

What should I be doing instead please? Thanks.

**docker-compose file 1** (excerpt) in 'nginx-proxy' folder:

```
services:
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs

volumes:
  certs:            // this produces a container called `nginx-proxy_certs`

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

**docker-compose file 2** (excerpt) in 'mailserver' folder:

```
services:
  mailserver:
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  certs:              // this produces a container called `mailserver_certs`

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: I would say if possible put both services in the same compose file, but if you need to keep them separate look at using external volumes https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#external-1  and you can see a potential example here https://codebeamer.com/cb/wiki/5713519

Comment: @camba1 Thank you very much, and upvoted. Question. in the 2nd link, this bit: `volumes:
  codebeamer-db-data:
    name: codebeamer-db-data
    external: true` ... why is the `name` replicated? Can it also be written as `volumes:
  codebeamer-db-data:
    external: true`... thanks!

Comment: The first one is the name is the alias used to refer to the volume within  the docker-compose file and the second is the reference to the actual external volume.